# Combobox popup is opened transparent

Tags: qt, qml

I have a Combobox (Control 2.0). I write my own combobox like

```
Rectangle
{
    border.width: 1
    border.color: "lightsteelblue"
    height:dp(40)
    width: parent.width

    ComboBox {
        id:tmCombo
        model:combotm.datalist
        textRole: "value"
        anchors.fill: parent
        currentIndex:-1;

        contentItem: Text {
            leftPadding: 0
            rightPadding: tmCombo.indicator.width + tmCombo.spacing

            text:tmCombo.currentIndex==-1 ? "":tmCombo.model[tmCombo.currentIndex].value
            font: tmCombo.font
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            elide: Text.ElideRight
        }

        onCurrentIndexChanged: {

            if(currentIndex!=-1) {
                var sqlid=model[currentIndex].sqlid;
                combotm.getsqlid(sqlid,1,Query.SelectSubParam,Query.Subq,"TMC",1);
                TaskResult.taskresult.HatBilgisi_TM=sqlid;
                tmsCombo.enabled=true;         
            }
            else {
                tmsCombo.enabled=false;
            }
            tmsCombo.currentIndex=-1;
        }


    }


}
```

My problem is that when Combobox first open, half of popup is transparent. Then I close and open combobox again. Everthing is OK. I am working in android platform.

**SOLUTION:** 
I have added import QtQuick.Templates 2.0 as T and chance Popup with T.Popup . That's work

Comment: ReferenceError: dp, combotm is not defined. A minimal example to work on, that runs out of the box and illustrates your problem would be nice.

Comment: @derM , dp and combotm is defined somewhere. I don't add all code

Comment: Yeah, and no one wants to write all the mysterious code for you, just to try your example. Therefore to provide a minimal example, you throw out all connections to "stuff defined somewhere else", that it runs out of the box, and still illustrates your problem. For further information, please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @derM , I don't think code is necessey. Combobox 's popup shows me half white , half transparent apperance once . Maybe it can be abuout to buffer

Comment: At least add your solution as an answer, not  as an edit inside the question.

Answer (score 2):

Rigth code is : Combobox with filter input :) I have binded model from C++ side with Q_Property . dp function is my global function in main.qml which is fixed pixel for any device.

```
    ComboBox {
                id:trCombo
                model:combotr.datalist
                textRole: "value"
                anchors.fill: parent
                currentIndex:-1;



                contentItem: Text {
                    leftPadding: 0
                    rightPadding: trCombo.indicator.width + trCombo.spacing

                    text:trCombo.currentIndex==-1 ? "":trCombo.model[trCombo.currentIndex].value
                    font: trCombo.font
                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                    elide: Text.ElideRight
                }

                popup: T.Popup {
                    id:mpopup
                    y: trCombo.height - (trCombo.visualFocus ? 0 : 1)

                    width: trCombo.width
                    implicitHeight: listview.contentHeight
                    topMargin: 6
                    bottomMargin: 6

                // focus: true
                    closePolicy: Popup.NoAutoClose

                    contentItem: Item {


                        Column
                        {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        spacing: 5
                        TextField
                        {

                        placeholderText: "arama yapın"
                        width: trCombo.width
                        height: dp(35)
                    // color: "red"
                        focus:true
                        inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhNoPredictiveText;

                        onTextChanged:{
                            //console.log("degisiyor");
                            process.filtertr(text);
                        }

                        onAccepted:{
                        //  console.log("Tasarım Bitti");
                            isfinished(true);
                        //  text="";


                        }




                        }

                        ListView {
                        id: listview
                        clip: true
                        model: trCombo.popup.visible ? trCombo.delegateModel : null
                        currentIndex: trCombo.highlightedIndex
                        width: trCombo.width
                        height:dp(500)


                        Rectangle {



                            z: 10
                            parent: listview
                            width: listview.width
                            height: listview.height
                            color: "transparent"
                            border.color: "#bdbebf"
                            layer.smooth: true
                        }

                        ScrollIndicator.vertical: ScrollIndicator { }
                    }

                    }
                }

                    background: Rectangle {  }

                    onClosed: {
                    if(!flag)
                    {
                        mpopup.open();
                    }

                    else
                    flag=false;
                    }


                }


                delegate: ItemDelegate {
                    width: trCombo.width
                    text: trCombo.textRole ? (Array.isArray(trCombo.model) ? modelData[trCombo.textRole] : model[trCombo.textRole]) : modelData
                    font.weight: trCombo.currentIndex === index ? Font.DemiBold : Font.Normal
                    highlighted: trCombo.highlightedIndex == index

                    onClicked: {
                        isfinished(true);
                    }
                }



                onCurrentIndexChanged: {

                    if(currentIndex!=-1)
                    {
                        var sqlid=model[currentIndex].sqlid;
                        combotr.getsqlid(sqlid,1,Query.SelectSubParam,Query.Subq,"TRC",1);
                        TaskResult.taskresult.HatBilgisi_TR=sqlid ;
                        trsCombo.enabled=true;


                    }

                    else
                        trsCombo.enabled=false;

                    trsCombo.currentIndex=-1;
                }


        }
```

Comment: `text: trCombo.textRole ? (Array.isArray(trCombo.model) ? modelData[trCombo.textRole] : model[trCombo.textRole]) : modelData`  
  
This line should really be part of Qt documentation. It's fundamental to produce working Controls styles.